# Clean destruction of a vector of dynamically alocated objects

Tags: c++, object, vector, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there another way of freeing the memory of the alocated objects, rather than iterating through the vector/list?

```
int main()
        {
            vector<Class*> v;
            v.push_back(new Class(2,2));
            v.push_back(new Class(65,65));
            v.push_back(new Class(45,23));
            for(Class* &it : v)
               delete it;
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: RAII. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Class>> v`

Comment: By not using a pointer at all, or by using [`RAII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) with a container like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Or, you could simply use `std::vector<Class>` and avoid the (possibly) unnecessary indirection.

Comment: Answers. Go. In. The. Answer. Section. Not difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is. it is called [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Class>> v;
v.push_back(std::make_unique<Class>(Class(2,5)));
```

However if you don't have a reason to use dynamically allocated objects, prefer `std::vector<Class>`.

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/OXY64x)